# Windows Phone 8.1 app upload a file to azure mobile app service

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, azure-media-services, azure-mobile-services

Continuing on fom the to-do items example I would like  to upload a video file captured on the phone with my app to azure mobile app service.
So instead of text a storage file is what I want to send.But cannot seem to find any information on this.
Any advice or examples of passing video files from an app to app service would be great.
With the ultimate goal is for my phone app to upload a file to the app service which I have running the sample upload and encode demo to azure media services.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas,

File management is actually one of the new features of Azure Mobile Apps.

You can find more information about it (including links to source and samples) here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/file-management-with-azure-mobile-apps/